# How to extend Selenium2Library by creating new RobotFramework keywords using Selenium WebDriver in Java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, python, robotframework, maven

I'm trying to extend the Selenium2Library python library (1.8.0) by implementing new Robot Framework keywords using Selenium WebDriver in Java.

In order to do that, I need to be able to retrieve the WebDriver instance used by the Selenium2Library python library in my Java keyword.

*Please note that I don't want to use the Java port of the Selenium 2 (WebDriver) Python library created by Markus Benhardt since it's based on an older version of Selenium2Library so it's clearly outdated.*

I've heard that with Jython 2.7, we can now use the Python version of Selenium2Library on Java... but my question is... how??

My setup is using :

- [Robot Framework Maven Plugin 1.4.7](http://robotframework.org/MavenPlugin/index.html)
- Robot Framework 3.0.2 (as a maven plugin dependency)
- Selenium Server 2.53.1 (as a maven plugin dependency)
- Selenium2Library python library (1.8.0)
- [Robot Framework Javalib Core 1.2.1](https://github.com/robotframework/JavalibCore)

Here's an extract of my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>robotframework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <extraPathDirectories>
            <extraPathDirectory>/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages</extraPathDirectory> 
        </extraPathDirectories>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- Robot Framework - High level test automation framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>robotframework</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Selenium Server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Does anyone has ever done something like that?